# Why does the imageview disappear on the layout?

Tags: android, layout

The imageview is on the right of the layout. It doesn't display if the content of messagedetail_row_text is too long. The imageview does display if the content of messagedetail_row_text is not too long.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dfdwasdfds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/outgoing"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="22dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/messagedetail_row_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/messagedetail_row_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messagedetail_row_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dfdwasdfds"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/messagegedetail_rov_icon2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/retouxiang" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you are looking for exactly. This is from what I understand:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/xyz"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/messagegedetail_rov_icon2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/retouxiang" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dfdwasdfds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/xyz"
        android:background="@drawable/outgoing"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="22dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/messagedetail_row_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="messagedetail_row_name"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/messagedetail_row_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:text="messagedetail_row_date"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messagedetail_row_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:text="messagedetail_row_text and this is a long text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dfdwasdfds"
            >


to
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_below="@id/dfdwasdfds"
        >
```

Comment: layout_below  will display the image under the content, but i just display the image on the right of the content.

Comment: You gave text width property fill_parent but parents layout has a width property wrap_content so it will take the space of right when it is long. No space for the imageview will disappear the image. @user2559787

Comment: You can try with a fixed width in the parent layout of the textView.

Comment: oh, is there any other solution? i just want set the control from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening because you have given your textView width fill_parent and it takes up as much space is its length is, then its parent width is wrap_content, so it goes upto its child occupies space(i.e TextView), so you dont have space to display the ImageView.

You can try using LinearLayout as root layout instead of relativeLayout..and manage your views by giving them weights..